# Compiler crashes when a Peer macro adds a property annotated with another Peer macro

Tags: swift, debugging, macros

When a peer macro adds another property marked with a different peer macro the compiler crashes with the error:

> Command SwiftCompile failed with a nonzero exit code

To recreate the problem:

```swift
public struct SecretNumberMacro: PeerMacro {
    public static func expansion(of node: AttributeSyntax,
                                 providingPeersOf declaration: some DeclSyntaxProtocol,
                                 in context: some MacroExpansionContext) throws -> [DeclSyntax] {

        return ["let secretNumber = 5"]  // << must be adding a property of some sort
    }
}
```

```swift
public struct SecretWordAndNumberMacro: PeerMacro {
    public static func expansion(of node: AttributeSyntax,
                                 providingPeersOf declaration: some DeclSyntaxProtocol,
                                 in context: some MacroExpansionContext) throws -> [DeclSyntax] {

        return ["@SecretNumber let secretWord = \"Hello\""]  // << Must use other Peer macro here
    }
}
```

and then simply using the macro will cause the error:

```swift
struct Person { 
    @SecretWordAndNumber var name = "John Doe"
}
```

If you were to remove the "@SecretNumber" from the `SecretWordAndNumberMacro` return value, the code will compile.

What is causing this issue and how to fix it? I tried to decode the error message but it was just a bunch of gibberish to me. The only thing of note was this line:

> 4. While emitting IR SIL function "@$s16ResettableClient6PersonC12secretNumberSivg".
>    for getter for secretNumber (at @_*swiftmacro_16ResettableClient6PersonC10secretWord0A0fMp*.swift:1:5)
>    Stack dump without symbol names (ensure you have llvm-symbolizer in your PATH or set the environment var `LLVM_SYMBOLIZER_PATH` to point to it):

("ResettableClient" is where the main.swift file is located)

##### Context

One of my macros wasn't working with the `@Observable` macro. My macro `@StoreInitial` would simply create a private constant prefixed with a "$" and initialised to the same value as the declaration you would attach it to.

However, I kept getting the following error:

> 'self' used in property access '$_name' before 'self.init' call

(which is what I expect to be causing the same problem with the code above)

I re-implemented the `@Observable` macro to see what was going wrong and I boiled it down to `@ObservationTracked` adding another property `@StoreInitial @ObservationIgnored var _name = "John Doe"` which was causing the issue. This had the same structure as the problem above: a Peer macro adding a declaration that has another Peer macro. So I'm assuming the problem causing the crash is also similar: using self in property access

Comment: Compiler crashes __always__ mean that you hit a bug in the compiler, so you should [raise a bug](https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/new?assignees=&labels=bug%2C+triage+needed&projects=&template=bug_report.md&title=) in the Swift GitHub project.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Just filed a bug report https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/69122